# Cannot run Preview in Xcode 13 RC

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, preview

I can't run SwiftUI Previews in Xcode since some betas and only in one project.

I keep getting the error

```
Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I can normally install the app on my phone and also run it in the simulator but not the preview for SwiftUI.

I don't know what's wrong and also this error message is not really helping.

Do you know a way to get a better error message to see what's causing the error?

I'm currently running Xcode 13 RC but it also happened with Beta 4 and 5

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: @TomášKafka I found my problem! I added a build phase where I compile Protobuf files once I removed that phase it works again. It used to work before... but also it doesn't work in the release version currently

Comment: @Fabio Yep - I found the cause, here's the writeup and solution: https://medium.com/@tomaskafka/fixing-the-dreaded-swiftui-paused-previews-8e9e20c502fe

Comment: @TomášKafka yeah I figured a way without using a build script for my protobuf. I'm using a build rule now instead and it works like a charm!